# Not able to connect to SQL Server instance with FreeTDS ODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds

I try to connect to a microsoft sql server

I use pyodbc with FreeTDS.

**My script:**

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=myServerAdress;INSTANCE =myInstanceName;PORT=myPortNumber;DATABASE=myDatabasename;UID=myUserName;PWD=myPassword')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

**Server is found but I get an error:**

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Fehler bei der Anmeldung für den Benutzer 'myUserName'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

**I think the translated error message is:**

> Fehler bei der Anmeldung für den Benutzer 'myUserName' = Login failed
>   for user ‘myUserName’.

So I thought the username or the password were wrong.
But connecting with the same credentials over tsql works fine.

```
tsql -S MyServerDSN -U myUsername -P myPassword
```

with

```
[MyServer]
host = myServername
instance = myInstanceName
```

works fine and I can select myDatabaseName and get results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [FreeTDS ODBC connection attributes documentation](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm) carefully. There is no `INSTANCE=` attribute. It says

> To specify a Microsoft SQL Server instance, use the form `server\instance`.

This works for me:

```python
cnxn_str = (
    r'DRIVER=FreeTDS;'
    r'SERVER=192.168.1.128\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=myDb;'
    r'UID=sa;PWD=whatever;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

Note also that you should specify an instance name **or** a port number, not both.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast help. Especially your last sentence gave me some more understanding. Was able to connect.

Comment: Also make sure that the database already exist. if not connect with tsql and run 1> CREATE DATABASE myDB;
2> go